# How to use Openstf with Virtual Device

Tags: eclipse, appium

1. How can I use Virtual device in OpenSTF
2. I want to test apk on multiple device?
3. But due to the fact I don't have real device

Comment: please add more detail

Comment: I want to run my script on multiple virtual script parallely how can i achieve that

Comment: Add more detail, Type of virtual device iOS, Android. Your platform, windows, ubuntu, etc. Have you done any research, If so what have you done so far.

Comment: Type of Virtual Device: Android
Platform:Ubuntu,windows
As per my research i can see OpenSTF is available only for real device

Is there any other open source tool useful for running multiple android virtual device for test automatiion